# What is the standard way to know the price of a chemical substance?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I've encountered many vendors with broadly varying prices for the same chemical substance, including amazon and Alibaba. I wonder if there is a standard way to know the universal/average price of a chemical substance.

Comment: Universal price is not a thing at all. As for the average price, you can get it by averaging the prices of all vendors, as simple as that.

Comment: But be careful that you're looking at the same "grade" or "quality" of the chemical. There is a vast difference in price between muriatic acid and ultra-pure hydrochloric acid.

Comment: Thank you for the comments,@MaxW I mean the same grade.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm asking here because the prices are very different which prompted me to ask about a standard or trusted way to know the price of a chemical as any other good that has an average price, economically speaking.

Comment: Well, it is pretty much the same as with any other type of goods on the market. There is nothing chemically specific about it. Take it or leave it. Or look around and hopefully you'll find a better deal. Or maybe not.

Comment: The price is the convergence of what you're prepared to pay for it and the seller is prepared to sell for ...  Sometimes a published "price" may be a useful guide but ... your question is one of economics rather than chemistry.

Comment: Cost-benefit is a part of any science, and the working scientist who is usually budget -bound is the best advice giver in this regard. isn't it ?@user1945827

Comment: @IvanNeretin it is doubtful f you see a vendor offering a good with, say 100 USD, another offering for 20 USD and a third for 280 $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Aldrich is a very well-known and reliable supplier for laboratory chemicals. They may not have the exact material you want, but if they have it, it is probably a good value. Start there and see if some other company can do better (and how quality differs). ChemicalStore.com is another supplier.

If you are seeking larger quantities (55 gallon drums or 50 pound bags), Spectrum is a possibility, or you may be interested in a larger (local) chemical distributor.

The best supplier is reliable and this may cost a bit. Establishing an account and being a continuing customer could gain you some help when you need it. Saving 5-10% on an item may not be worth it if it causes you to price-shop - you will be shopping and hopping all the time.

Comment: What is the meaning of price-shop?

Comment: Price-shopping is shopping for a better price for the same or similar product, without considering other factors like quality, availability (how soon), reliability, service, and perhaps manufacturing location.

Comment: I found this useful answer on quora:For laboratory amounts a good chemical supply catalog, such as Aldrich,

For commodities it is more difficult. A starting point is the ICIS Chemical Price Guide: Chemicals A-Z